# Error:Abnormal build process termination - Idea выдаёт ошибку при запуске проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

При попытке запуска проекта на IDEA 2019.2 вылетает ошибка Error:Abnormal build process termination. Буквально вчера (да и вообще до этого) я с ней не сталкивался, IDE не менял и не обновлял. От проекта тоже не зависит - пробовал запускаться на простом helloworld'е - всё равно кидает ошибку.

Перезапуск, переустановка IDEA не помогли.
Удалял временную папку .IntelliJIdea2019.2, конфиги, перезапускался - ошибка остаётся.

В похожих вопросах советовали драйвер Nvidia обновить - только что попробовал, тоже без результата.

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m - 
Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true - 
Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true - 
Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true - 
Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=7753059037608542850 -Dfile.encoding=windows-            
1251 -Duser.language=ru -Duser.country=RU - 
Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2019.2 "-Didea.home.path=D:\Java\IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2" - 
Didea.config.path=C:\Users\anabiozzze/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config - 
Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\anabiozzze/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/plugins - 
Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/anabiozzze/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/log/build-log "- 
Djps.fallback.jdk.home=D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/jbr" - 
Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.3 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true - 
Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/anabiozzze/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/compile- 
server/npa_c1dd41ac/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true - 
Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true 
-Dkotlin.daemon.enabled Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\ANABIO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin- 
idea-11808805782515027630-is-running\" -classpath "D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk- 
11.0.6/lib/classes.zip" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/lib/asm-all-7.0.1.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/forms-1.1- 
preview.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/lib/netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/util.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/netty-buffer- 
4.1.36.Final.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/trove4j.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/resources_en.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.36.Final.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/lib/log4j.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/annotations.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/commons-logging- 
1.2.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-connector-basic- 
1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-builder- 
support-3.3.9.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/httpcore- 
4.4.11.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-aether- 
provider-3.3.9.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/jna-platform.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/jps- 
model.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/maven-artifact- 
3.3.9.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/plexus-utils- 
3.0.22.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport- 
http-1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/jdom.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA      
2019.2/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/jna.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/netty-common- 
4.1.36.Final.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether- 
transport-file-1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/platform-api.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/guava-25.1- 
jre.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/netty-codec- 
4.1.36.Final.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-api- 
1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency- 
resolver.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/aether-impl- 
1.1.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/java/lib/commons-lang3- 
3.4.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/protobuf-java- 
3.5.1.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/lib/idea_rt.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/httpclient-4.5.8.jar;;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/lib/guava-25.1-jre.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/common-26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt- 
constants.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse- 
util.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/osmorc/lib/biz.aQute.bndlib- 
4.2.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA      
2019.2/plugins/osmorc/lib/biz.aQute.repository-4.2.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/osmorc/lib/biz.aQute.resolve-4.2.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/webSphere-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin- 
stdlib.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin- 
reflect.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/android- 
common.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/build- 
common.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/android- 
rt.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/android-extensions- 
ide.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common-26.3.0- 
sp1.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/common- 
26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/repository- 
26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2/plugins/android/lib/sdklib- 
26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA      
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api-26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger-26.3.0.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps- 
plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ 
IDEA 2019.2/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar;D:/Java/IntelliJ IDEA 
2019.2/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar" 
org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 53379 1469537e-61de-4fd7-9dcf- 
ea5b97e369c2 C:/Users/anabiozzze/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/system/compile- 
server
```

Answer (score 0):

Переустановка JDK + удаление всех временных файлов Idea решили проблему.